# C# listener of an event in a child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a chess-like game in unity (c#) and i'm getting stuck trying to do an upcasting to send information from a child to another of an abstract class.

Basically, I have an abstract class that has an event/delegate with a function so it can be accessed by a child class like this:

```
public delegate void KingUnderAttack(int CurrentX, int CurrentY, int CurrentAttackerX, int CurrentAttackery, System.Type attacker, bool isKingWhite);
public event KingUnderAttack kingUnderAttack;

protected void RaiseKingUnderAttack(int CurrentX, int CurrentY, int CurrentAttackerX, int CurrentAttackerY, System.Type attacker, bool isKingWhite)
{
    if (kingUnderAttack != null)
    {
        kingUnderAttack(CurrentX, CurrentY, CurrentAttackerX, CurrentAttackerY, attacker, isKingWhite);
    }
}
```

and in my child Class i access it like this:

```
RaiseKingUnderAttack(CurrentX, CurrentY, x, y, typeof(Knight), isWhite);
```

and on the recieving child class:

```
private void Start()
{
    kingUnderAttack += Knight_kingUnderAttack;
}

private void Knight_kingUnderAttack(int CurrentX, int CurrentY, int CurrentAttackerX, int CurrentAttackerY, System.Type attacker, bool isKingWhite)
{
    Debug.Log(CurrentX);
    Debug.Log(CurrentY);
    Debug.Log(CurrentAttackerX);
    Debug.Log(CurrentAttackerY);
    Debug.Log(attacker);
    Debug.Log(isKingWhite);
}
```

by debugging I could see that the abstract class receives the child information but the information doesn't reach the second child class. I'm really stuck trying to think why.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of inheritance. _Instances_ of a  "Child" class do not share (non-static) class fields of the base class. They have their own "copy" if you will. To simplify this, think of it as the children having the event declared directly in opposition to through a base class. Two instances will have their distinct sets of event registrees.  If you _want_ the described behavior, then there are various ways to achieve this. So if my assumptions are true, this is a x-y-question.

Comment: Please post minimal class definitions. This talk of "second child class" and "recieving child class" is confusing. However, I suspect the issue is... what Fildor has just beaten me to posting :)

Comment: As i said, i'm pretty new to this. So it could very well be an x-y question indeed. To clarify, i'm trying to send information between two classes that inherit from an abstract one. Maybe there is an easier way/complete diferent way and i'm willing to learn :D

Comment: Very well. Did you understand why what you tried does not work as you expected? We first have to get this out of the way.

Comment: If my assumptions are not wrong, because each class has a copy of the base class instead of using it. They will have have their own event registrees not interconnected between themselves so they will not send information to one another.

Comment: @AdrianSgro more or less, but I wouldn't call it a "copy" of the base class, simply to avoid confusion with composition where you literally do store a reference to a class inside your class. The base class is more like a template to "generate" the derived classes, so they each get a "copy" of the base class source code and 2 independent classes are created. I think what you want to do is move the event into a game board class and subscribe to events published by that game object.

Comment: Thank you all very much! i just did what @Colin Young recommended via an instance of my board and it works perfectly. This is my first post on stackoverflow and i got a solution in a few minutes. You guys rock!

Comment: @ColinYoung you should post this as an answer for future viewers.

Comment: @TJWolschon Done. I guess the implied question was "how do I orchestrate subscribing every peer to each other's events?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance can be thought of as a sort of code template that is "inserted" into the source of the child class, therefore the descendant classes are completely independent of each other. Assuming your child classes are the game pieces and you are wanting to alert all of the pieces to the event, it's not going to work if your child class is raising the event. That is, unless every child object subscribes to that event on every other child object (we'll ignore the n<sup>2</sup> event subscriptions for now), in which case, you're going to need to keep track of every child somewhere central, and if you're going to do that...

A better approach is to add the event to a `GameObject` representing your game board (i.e. the class that orchestrates the pieces, game rules, etc., let's call that `BoardManager`). The `BoardManager` is responsible for subscribing to events on each piece and publishing events of interest to each piece (now we've only got 2n event subscriptions). This approach isn't all that far from the [Flux architecture pattern](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts).

(I'm going to use chess names in this example - and boy do I wish SO had a sequence diagram feature)

1. `Knight` notifies `BoardManager` it wants to move to `x, y`
2. `BoardManager` checks validity, tells `Knight` to move to `x, y`
3. `Knight` tells `BoardManager` "I'm done moving"
4. `BoardManager` notices that `King` is under attack and sends out a notification to every piece of that fact
5. Each piece individually does whatever it is they are supposed to do when `King` is under attack...